# How to getRange() of a group of cells while doing iteration in a Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I want to check if there is any blank cells in a given range and trying to use below code for that. Problem is Range is not certain and subject to change with every iteration. 
I tried something like `getRange('A'+ row : 'H'+ row)` but its in wrong syntax. Can someone help me with this issue ? Thanks!

```js
var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Red'); // Get worksheet
var endRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get current active spreadsheet.
var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Template');
var runloop = true;
var startRow = 3;

for (var row = startRow; row <= endRow; row++) {

    var sheet_name = sheet1.getRange("A" + row).getValue(); // Get the JD number for the file name.
    var range = sheet1.getRange('A' + row: 'H' + row);

    if (range.isBlank()) {
        # Dome Something here
    }
}
```

Comment: *if there is any blank cells* That's not how isblank works. It returns true only if **all** the range is blank.

Comment: So is there any other command that does the job instead of isblank ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You can *concatenate* the `A1Notation` before passing it to `getRange()`

### Example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  for (var row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
    var rangeA = "A" + row;
    var rangeB = "H" + row;
    var range = rangeA + ":" + rangeB;

    Logger.log(range);

    // Get the JD number for the file name.
    var sheet_name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rangeA).getValue(); 
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range);

    if (range.isBlank()) {

      Logger.log(range.getA1Notation() + " is blank!.");

    }
  }
}
```

## Output log from the example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Utilities.formatString](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatstringtemplate,-args)

```
var range = sheet1.getRange(Utilities.formatString('A%s:H%s', row, row));
```

For [V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime)

```
const range = sheet1.getRange(`A${row}:H${row}`);
```

Comment: Elegant solution